# Facebook Graph API search people within a city

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, web-crawler

Does anyone know if it's possible to use Facebook's Graph API to query all the people within a city?

If that's not possible, would it work if I post AJAX request that simulate the action of scroll page down in the search page?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It´s not possible to get all people in a city, you can only search for users by name: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search

Simulating with AJAX is not allowed because that would be scraping: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Comment: Can I also search all users named "John" within a specific city, say, New York? If yes, can you post an example please? Thank you!

Comment: no, that´s not possible. you can ONLY search for users by name. OR search for a place by latitude/longitude. see the first link i posted.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just tried using https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=john&type=user&fields=name&access_token=, it displayed a number of users, then there's a paging.next field that gives you a link (which I guess is supposed to be the link to the next page of users). But when trying to access this link, all it does it show you the link of previous page. Does anyone know why?